# Submit form without refresh - jQuery, ajax - IE not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, validation

I'm trying to get contact form working properly. Here http://pagina.chalupakoseckerovne.sk/ at end of the page is contact form. Validation using jquary.validate plugin workd, but now i cant find out how to stay on page after submit without refresh and show short message next to submit button like "Thank you".
Here is my validation script

```
$("#contact-form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {minlength: 4,required: true},
            email: {required: true,email: true},
            phone: {number: true,required: true},
            pocet: {range: [1, 10],required: true},
            odkedy: {required: true},
            dokedy: {required: true}
        },   
    });
    $('#contact-form').ajaxForm(function() { 
        $("#done").show("slow");
        $('#contact-form').resetForm();
    }); 
    return false;
```

And here is my php:

```
<?php 
$ToEmail = 'sample@email.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Chalupa-rezervacia'; 
$mailheader = "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1250"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = 'Meno: '.$_REQUEST["name"].'<br />
                Email: '.$_REQUEST["email"].'<br />
                Tel. cislo: '.$_REQUEST["phone"].'<br />
                Pocet: '.$_REQUEST["pocet"].'<br />
                Prichod: '.$_REQUEST["odkedy"].'<br />
                Odchod: '.$_REQUEST["dokedy"].'<br />
                Poznamka: '.$_REQUEST["comments"].'<br />'; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader);
?>
```

form

```
<form name="contact-form" id="contact-form" action="rezervacia.php" method="post">
```

*EDIT:*now works fine in Chrome, FF and Opera but no in IE. In IE just redirect to php.

Comment: you're going to want to use ajax form submit in some fashion. check out http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Seems like this is what ajax is for. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Do an ajax `POST` request instead of the form submit

Comment: I second what @Colleen said. $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {});

Comment: Thanks, works great except IE 8,9. IE just run php and show blank page. In Chrome, Opera and FF works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a submit handler with an ajax post function for your validate function. Something like this should do it:

```
$('#contact-form').validate({
   rules: {
      name: {minlength: 4,required: true},
      email: {required: true,email: true},
      phone: {number: true,required: true},
      pocet: {range: [1, 10],required: true},
      odkedy: {required: true},
      dokedy: {required: true}
   },
   submitHandler: function(form) {
      // some other code
      // maybe disabling submit button
      // post the form data with ajax

      $.ajax({
          url: 'process.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: form.serialize(),         
          success: function(data) {
              // Show any returned message
              alert('Load was performed: ' + data);
          }
      });

      // Prevent form submission
      return false;
   }
});
```

See the jquery.validate plugin docs here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation
And also the jQuery ajax docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**--- EDIT ---**

As per Ryleys comment below I've added `return false;` to the `submitHandler` which will prevent the form submission. Here's an example of the shorthand `$.post` function which you can use as an alternative to the `$.ajax` function:

```
$.post('process.php', form.serialize(), function(data) {
    // Show any returned message
    alert('Load was performed: ' + data);
});
```

See jQuery $.post docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: thanks. and what should I put in form tag as action<
`<form name="contact-form" id="contact-form" action="" method="post">`

Comment: @mascot - you don't need to put anything there.  the `url: 'process.php'` is taking care of submitting the form for you.  I would recommend using `$.post` and also `return false;` at the end of the `submitHandler` function...

Comment: Ah nice catch @Ryley, should've added `return false;`, have added an edit and included a shorthand `$.post` example :)